# d3js use a function inside d3.select(...)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and I am trying to get an attribute from an array of objects.

The issue I am having is `.attr("y", d3.select(function(d, i){ return data[i].id;}).attr("y"))` gives me an error. I want to get the id from an array of objects. I know that specific id exists because I am trying to add text into a rect and the object is already created. Is there a way I can get the id from my array of objects and get its attribute of y?

Comment: You have to wrap the anonymous function around the selection, not the other way around. But what's the point of doing this? Why not simply setting it as you did the first time?

Comment: Because I am going back to the id to make changes that arise later.

Comment: Still, it doesn't make sense. `data[I]` is the same of `d`, and in that case its simply `this`. So, you're selecting `this` and setting the y attribute according to the y attribute... I'm not following this. Can you provide a working scenario?